# Wrap superglobal $_GET inside a class property

Tags: php, superglobals

The goal is to get some precise values of `$_GET` in a property of a class while:

1. removing any key not desired
2. defaulting values when keys are not defined

With this code in a file `/request.php`:

```
$req = new request();
var_dump($req);
class request {
  private $Get;
  function __construct() {
    $this->Get = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET,array (
      'menu'=>array (
        'filter'=>FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'options'=>array (
          'default'=>30,
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

from [php's man page for filter_input_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) about the third parameter (true by default):

> Add missing keys as NULL to the return value.

I would expect that calling `domain.com/request.php` would yield a defaulted [sic] array with the integer 30 as `menu`'s value. however when no `$_GET` are defined (that is, when there's no character after a question mark in the url) filter_input_array returns `null` therefore the var_dump is this:

> object(request)#1 (1) { ["Get":"request":private]=> NULL }

however when `$_GET` is defined (that is, having at least one character after the question mark in the url) such as calling `domain.com/request.php?a` will yield:

> object(request)#1 (1) { ["Get":"request":private]=> array(1) { ["menu"]=> NULL } }

**How can I force `filter_input_array()` to return an array so that default values will be built even if I call an url with no $_GET value defined like `index.php`?**

It seems possible to rewrite a request from .htaccess so that I could mimic a $_GET value being defined if there are not, but it feels weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use another simple way?

```
var_dump(filter_var_array($_GET, array(
  'key' => FILTER_DEFAULT,
), true));
```